# Undefined type 'Validator'.intelephense(1009)

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, intelephense

Can anyone help me with this error? Im new to laravel and i was making a productController file but im getting this error from Validator:

[image]

I have called use Validator; What else can i do

Comment: Do you have the corresponding `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` on the top of your file?

Comment: Yeah i think it was just intelephense error

Comment: I would recommend you 100% to switch to PHPStorm, it is paid, but if you or your company can afford the license, you will not have these issues and you will get a big help. You can also try PHPStorm EAP (Beta release) that one is free but could have errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the following package:

```
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

After, run:

```
php artisan ide-helper:models
php artisan ide-helper:generate
php artisan ide-helper:meta
```

And finally, install this extension on your vs code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgykurian.laravel-ide-helper

Also, another good to have (optional): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

It should solve your problem.

Comment: `php artisan ide:meta` will not work, it only works for `phpstorm` becuase it is a file only that IDE can understand

Comment: Sure! But its interesting use it for a future developer that can use phpstorm

Answer (score 1):

I've came across this issue as well. I've fixed this one with [Laraphense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=porifa.laravel-intelephense).

It fixes the issue with the vanilla Intelephense.

You can either install it via:

- URL - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=porifa.laravel-intelephense
- VS Code Extension Name: Laraphense

This is its VSC page:
[image: Laraphense in VS Code]